# Inverted text when rendering text in Cairo

Tags: c++, c, cairo

I am writing a program using Cairo where I need to change the coordinates from screen to Cartesian using the following code:

```
cairo_translate( cr, x, height );
cairo_scale( cr, 1.0, -1.0 ); // FLIP the Y axis
```

But when I try to render text (cairo_show_text), the text is inverted also and, hence, unreadable.

The same happens when using a scaled font (cairo_scaled_font_t):

```
cairo_font_options_t *font_options;
cairo_matrix_t ctm, font_matrix;
cairo_scaled_font_t *scaled_font;


font_options = cairo_font_options_create();
cairo_get_matrix( cr, &ctm );
cairo_get_font_matrix( cr, &font_matrix );

font_matrix.xx = font_matrix.yy = 20.0; // font size

// font_face initialized elsewhere and is valid

scaled_font = cairo_scaled_font_create( font_face, &font_matrix, &ctm, font_options );

cairo_set_scaled_font( cr, scaled_font );

cairo_move_to( cr, 1, 50 );

cairo_show_text( cr, "some text" );

...
```

I think the matrix needs some adjustments, but I don't know how. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The text is upside down. For example, 'L' looks like a Gamma, and 'W' looks like an 'M'.

Comment: By inverted, you mean, along the X-axis or the Y-axis?

Comment: Or do you mean color-inverted?

Comment: I think he means upside down, since there's a Y scale of -1.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Unwind is correct: upside down. For example, the letter 'L' looks like a Gamma, or 'W' like an 'M'.

Answer (score 2):

Theres two ways to do this that I know:

```
cairo_matrix_t ms, mt, m;
cairo_matrix_init_scale(&ms, 1.0f, -1.0f);
cairo_matrix_init_translate(&mt, 0.0f, -m_height);
cairo_matrix_multiply(&m, &mt, &ms);
cairo_set_matrix(cr, &m);
```

or:

```
cairo_scale(cr, 1.0f, -1.0f);
cairo_translate(cr, 0.0f, -m_height);
```

Both solved the problem for me. Scale the cr by the -1 on y, but that means the text is off the surface, so translate by the -height of the surface and it should sit right.

Answer (score 1):

Since you flip the coordinate system upside down, text is also shown upside down.  The solution to this problem is to manually flip back text, by setting a font matrix with a negative entry for the vertical scale.  You can do this, by modifying your code for setting the font size like this:

```
double font_size = 20.0;
font_matrix.xx = font_size;
font_matrix.yy = -font_size; // negative size to vertically flip text
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are flipping the Y-axis, thus the text gets flipped, too. Try this:

```
cairo_save(cr);
cairo_reset_clip(cr);
cairo_show_text(cr, "Some Text");
cairo_restore(cr);
```

The above replaces the cairo_show_text() call in your example.

Comment: I believe your code will only affect the "clip region" (this is what `cairo_reset_clip` does), but will not cure the text problem.  To flip the text, fiddling with coordinate transformation matrices is required.

Comment: Isn't the question saying that the text is flipped, but he wants it to be unflipped? But yeah, dunno what I was thinking with this cairo_reset_clip() call, I guess I meant cairo_identify_transform().

Comment: The text is flipped, so adding a second flip and unflipping is the same thing.  And I agree that a solution based on cairo_identity_transform might work.